# Client Server Pausing/Resuming/Closing with Thread State

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have a client running that I'm trying to pause/resume or close when given a certain input. If "!" is entered, then it pauses the thread or resumes the thread depending on if it was running or not. And if "#" is entered whether its running or not, the thread is closed.

I think I am close, but I am having a little trouble. Heres my code:

```
while(true) {
                Thread.State state = t.getState();
                if(state == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
                    if(input.nextLine().equals("!")) {
                        t.suspend();
                        System.out.println("Sleeping");
                        System.out.println(state);
                    }
                    else if(input.nextLine().equals("#")) {
                        t.stop();
                        System.out.println("Closing");
                        System.out.println(state);
                    }
                }
                if(state == Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) {
                    if(input.nextLine().equals("!")) {
                        t.resume();
                        System.out.println("Resuming");
                        System.out.println(state);
                    }
                    else if(input.nextLine().equals("#")) {
                        t.stop();
                        System.out.println("Closing");
                        System.out.println(state);
                    }
                }
            }

            }
```

This code kind of works. But if I want to close the thread, I have to enter # twice for it to close.

Comment: Might be a buffer flush problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are far from good.

You should avoid any using of [Thread#pause()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend()), [Thread#resume()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#resume()) and [Thread.stop()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) especially Thread.stop(). They are deprecated functions and sooner or later many be not implemented in future version of JDK.

The suggested way to implement what you want it to send a signal (optionally, an addition interrupt) to the thread, and the thread itself aware of signal change and do enter the target state by itself.

Ref: [Why is Thread.stop deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)